yarn get error:Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
I install node_modules for my project.
yarn
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
warning knight-operation: "dependencies" has dependency "@testing-library/jest-dom" with range "^4.2.4" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "^5.11.6"
warning knight-operation: "dependencies" has dependency "@testing-library/react" with range "^9.3.2" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "^11.2.2"
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "css-loader@3.4.2" is incompatible with requested version "css-loader@4.3.0"
[3/5]   Fetching packages...
error http://registry.m.jd.com/fsevents/download/fsevents-1.2.7.tgz: Integrity check failed for "fsevents" (computed integrity doesn't match our records, got "sha512-+ux3lx6peh0BpvY0JebGyZoiR4D+oYzdPZMKJwkZ+sFkNJzpL7tXc/wehS49gUAxg3tmMHPHZkA8JU2rhhgDHw== sha1-Z79X9HWPAu3oj7KhcS/vTRU1i+M=")
[4/5]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > css-loader@3.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning " > @dada/custom@0.2.10" has incorrect peer dependency "lodash@^4.17.15".
warning "webpack-config-single-spa-react > webpack-config-single-spa > standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin@1.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@*".
error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/sunbin94/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-fsevents-1.2.11-4851b664a3783e52003b3c66eb0eee1074933aa4-integrity/node_modules/fsevents/.yarn-metadata.json'
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

How to slove it？？I have tried every method i can find，but none of them worked.For example:
yarn cache clean
yarn install --network-timeout 10000000
yarn install --network-concurrency 1
rm -rf node_modules **/node_modules
rm -rf yarn.lock **/yarn.lock
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
I want to install node_modules successful

Looks like your Yarn cache is corrupted. Try cleaning it with the --all or --mirror options ~ https://yarnpkg.com/cli/cache/clean

@Phil Still not working
